# como solucionar el error en un arreglo que no recibe datos y no los imprime datos en java

Tags: java

Estoy practicando programación con menus, de distintas formas, pero tengo un error en un arreglo
que no recibe los datos,el ejercicio es: crear un arreglo con menu, que ingrese el tamaño, los datos, y los imprima. usando sentencias if.

```
import java.io.*;
public class arreglo{
public static void main(String args [ ])throws IOException{
 BufferedReader al = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int dato=0, op=0;
 boolean chismes = true;
 while(chismes){
System.out.println(" \n Bienvenido");
        System.out.println("1.- tamano del arreglo");
        System.out.println("2.- Ingresar datos");
        System.out.println("3.- mostrar datos");
        System.out.println("4.- Salir");
        System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion");
        op = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
        if(op==1){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo");
        dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
        int [] array = new int[dato];
        }
        else if(op==2){                
        for(int i=0; i<dato; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese sus datos");
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
        }
}else if(op==3){       
            System.out.println("\n Sus datos son");
            for(int i=0;i<dato;i++){
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
    } 
  }else if(op == 4){
            chismes = false;
        }
     }      
}
```

error:

```
arreglo.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
             array[i] = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
symbol:   variable array

location: class arreglo
arreglo.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
symbol:   variable array
```

location: class arreglo
2 errors

Comment: No has declarado la variable ```array```, sllo lo has echo en el bloque del ```if(op==1)``` y no el otro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema

> error: cannot find symbol

indica que no puede encontrar la definiciòn de alguna variable y esto es debido a que no tienes el alcance (scope) de la variable array, debes declararla para que sea usada dentro de cualquier punto de tu `while` :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader al = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int dato = 0, op = 0;
        boolean chismes = true;
         //*Declara variable array.
        int[] array = null;
        while (chismes) {
            System.out.println(" \n Bienvenido");
            System.out.println("1.- tamano del arreglo");
            System.out.println("2.- Ingresar datos");
            System.out.println("3.- mostrar datos");
            System.out.println("4.- Salir");
            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion");
            op = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
            if (op == 1) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo");
                dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
                //int[] array = new int[dato];
                array = new int[dato];
            } else if (op == 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dato; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese sus datos");
                    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
                }
            } else if (op == 3) {
                System.out.println("\n Sus datos son");
                for (int i = 0; i < dato; i++) {
                    System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                }
            } else if (op == 4) {
                chismes = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: gracias, me ha funcionado :D

Comment: Excelente Juan!, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

estas creando una array dentro de un if, esto significa que fuera no existirá, el error se soluciona creando la array justo antes del while.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader al = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int dato = 0, op = 0;
        boolean chismes = true;
          int[] array = new int[dato]; // Array Instanciado
        try {
            while (chismes) {

                System.out.println(" \n Bienvenido");
                System.out.println("1.- tamano del arreglo");
                System.out.println("2.- Ingresar datos");
                System.out.println("3.- mostrar datos");
                System.out.println("4.- Salir");
                System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion");

                op = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());

                if (op == 1) {

                    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo");
                    dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
                    array= new int[dato];
                  
                } else if (op == 2) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dato; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese sus datos");
                        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
                    }
                } else if (op == 3) {
                    System.out.println("\n Sus datos son");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dato; i++) {
                        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                    }
                } else if (op == 4) {
                    chismes = false;
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: gracias. me ha funcionado :D